# Can we update a normal field and a nested array field at the same time in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a product schema like

```
 quantity: { type: Number, required: true },
    batch_no: {
        type: [

            {

                batch_no: { type: String, required: true },
                quantity: { type: Number, required: true },
                created_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now() },



            }

        ],
        default: []
    }
```

I am trying to update both the quantity fields in one query.

The code goes something like :

```
var expression = { $and: [{ "$inc": { "quantity": -10 } }, { "$inc": {"batch_no.$.batch_no": -10 } }] }

await ProductModel.findOneAndUpdate({ "sku": "TestSKU", "batch_no.$.batch_no":"Batch 1" }, { expression }, (err, response) => {
                if (response) {
                    console.log("Update success")

                } else if (err) {
                    res.status(400).send(err);
                }
            });
```

This nested query does not work.

Is there no way that I can update both the quantites at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[$and](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) is a query operator. If you just wanted to update multiple fields via [$inc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/), you can pass them as key-value pairs object argument to $inc, like this:

```
var expression = { $inc: { "quantity": -10, "batch_no.$.batch_no": -10 } }

await ProductModel.findOneAndUpdate({ "sku": "TestSKU", "batch_no.$.batch_no": "Batch 1" }, expression, (err, response) => {
    if (response) {
        console.log("Update success")

    } else if (err) {
        res.status(400).send(err);
    }
});
```

Also, you can just pass in `expression` directly as the 2nd argument, without wrapping it in another object.